# PHP requires hard reload to update

Tags: php, session

Im writing a basic site that you log in to using a database and forms. I want it so if you are logged in, it says, You are logged in and You are logged out for when they arnt logged in on the homepage.

Atm I have this code (Its basic but does the job for now)

```
function checkSession(){
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . 'home/drewmcmi/tmp/'));
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(!array_key_exists("uid",$_SESSION) || $_SESSION['uid'] === null){
    return false;
}
return true;    
}
```

This code is then put on the actual home page and the top code is included once before it

```
if(checkSession()){
echo 'You are logged in';
}else{
echo 'You are logged out';
}
```

This works, but only if you do a hard reload of the page. if you just navigate to the page it wont update despite logging in and setting the session. It requires a hard reset to show the real outcome.

Is there a way to ensure that whenever you load the page it is correct. Atm if you go to the login page, then get sent to the 'hub'(logged in area), If you go to the homepage, where the second code is, it shows logged out until you hard reset

Thanks :)

Comment: did you start the session for **all** files using sessions? the 2nd code block should check if the session is set/empty

Comment: The second code block runs the first code block though? Doesnt the first do that?

Comment: if it's in the same file, sure. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php see if anything comes of it

Comment: Yeah nothing comes up :P